# script is not getting variable from GET

Tags: php

I have code in /user.php:

```
<?php
$thisuser = $_GET['user'];
echo $thisuser;
?>
```

And i write in browser:  /user.php?user=Maria
And the website do not echo anything. What is wrong about it?

I actually have a ajax script that should send there a variable by get but it do not work at all.

EDIT here is the whole thing:

```
echo '<div class="thisphotobox"><div class="photouser">' . 'Dodał:<a href="user.php?user=' . $numphotos["user"] . '" " class="proflink" onclick="prof(\''.$profuser.'\')"> '.$numphotos["user"].'</a></div>';


<script>
    function prof(profuser){
    var xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "user.php?user=" + profuser, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Post your script with your ajax call. That should work what you do! Your code looks correct if you open the file over the browser.

Comment: I already added the rest of code

Comment: If you call your script in your browser it should really work and echo your get parameter... Perhaps make an echo before...

Comment: The code in every language hates me. I will never be programmer :(

Comment: You dont access the response from the ajax call, so how do you know its not working? add `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {alert(this.responseText);}`

Comment: After adding this at the end of script. 
I have 3 alerts. First is empty, and the two next are showing the whole website code. What does it actually mean xD?

Comment: @Steve The whole AJAX thing doesn't matter if the landing page doesn't output the GET variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to the `<a>` tag's default behavior preventing your function to execute on click.

Since you are setting the URL inside the prof() function, you don't need he `href` value inside the `<a>` tag, so you could do something like this:

```
echo '<div class="thisphotobox"><div class="photouser">' . 'Dodał:<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="proflink" onclick="prof(\''.$profuser.'\')"> '.$numphotos["user"].'</a></div>';
```

Note that I just set the `href` value to `javascript:void(0);`. So now `onClick` should take effect and the prof() function should be invoked.

** Visually verify if it's working: **

Use this javascript code:

```
<script>
function prof(profuser)
{
    var xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ( (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status==200) )
        {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "user.php?user=" + profuser, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Then you will also have to add, in the same file where the javascript code is, the following:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Finally, please make sure you are properly closing the PHP tags `<?php ?>` and make sure that only PHP code is inside that block. HTML and Javascript must be outside that block.

Comment: Thank you for answer :) But i will have to get to the user.php page. How do i do that otherway after function gets executed :D?
Anyways my php script is not working even if i manually add to url the value to the variable

Comment: Your PHP part is actually working **correctly** given what it does. The question is: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: All i want to do is to create user.php page where are information about particular user of my website. Clicking on the link should sent the nick of the user through the ajax and then i want to get to that page and see the info. Something like when you press someones nick on facebook. Its just the same idea

Comment: Ok, please take a look at the new info in the answer, I hope that will throw some light in the whole thing. Please, remember to properly close PHP tags <?php with the corresponding ?>

In your Javascript you need to capture the response sent back from your user.php (explained in the edit).

Comment: I am honestly not sure what it does but it writes on my website word "undefined". But anyway i accept this all as answer and i will + you when i get more reputation points coz its impossible now :P
Thank you for your patience

Comment: My bad! I gave you how to do it with synchronous requests. Please take a look at the javascript portion now for how to do it for asynchronous.  By the way, whether is sync or async is given by the third parameter to the call xmlhttp.open(). It is true, so async. That is why you were seeing "undefined". I apologize, please try it and let me know :)

Comment: Good! Now, try changing the user.php so it returns HTML containing the user's profile. Just remember, you don't need to return a full HTML page with <html><head><body>... just return the profile information.

Answer (score -5):

The AJAX script will send the data by POST not by GET.

GET is to 'get' the value, POST is to pass the value.

You also only use the send() value for POST, so change the GET to POST in the AJAX.

Also, you need to declare your script BEFORE you call it in the HTML.